# Trying to Concatenate Object names in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, concatenation

I know I can concatenate a variable name using stringwithformat, but is it possible to concatenate an object name?  I'm not having any luck working around this one.

image+1.hidden = YES; for example.

If I wanted to loop through that, say 10 times, how would I create the 'image+1' part?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not use an NSMutableArray or NSArray and iterate through it?

Comment: What part of this question deals with XCode? This is just Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to concatenate object names in objective c, but you could create an array of images, and then reference each image like

```
image[0].hidden = YES;
```

That would fit the for loop. You could also add the images (I assume that they are UIImages) to an NSArray, then loop through like so:

```
NSArray* arrayOfImages;

for(UIImage* image in arrayOfImages)
{
    image.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the objects to an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`. Then loop through the array to set each object's properties.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of discussion mainly, you can use key-value coding to set a property by its name. So,  supposing you had `instance`, an instance of a class that provides the properties `image1`, `image2` and `image3` then you could perform:

```
for(int x = 1; x < 4; x++)
{
    // produce the name of the property as an NSString
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", x];

    // use key-value coding to set the property
    [instance setValue:someValue forKey:propertyName];
}
```

For the full list of accessor methods that compliant classes export, see the [NSKeyValueCoding Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). `NSObject` implements `NSKeyValueCoding`, and all properties declared as `@property` and implemented as `@synthesize` are compliant, as are any other properties with suitable accessors.

As already noted in the other answers, when what you want is an ordered list of objects so that you can do something with each in turn, either a C-style array or an NSArray is the correct way to proceed, with an NSArray being preferred for style reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, nil]; // or use NSMutableArray
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
     ((UIImage*)[array objectAtIndex:x]).hidden = YES;
}
```